# Push. Внутренние папки в репозитории

Tags: git, bitbucket

Запушил на bitbucket свой локальный репозиторий, но папка(не пустая), которая была в нем не добавилась. Как ее запушить? Использую программу Git GUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git не версионирует папки сами по себе, только файлы. Чтобы добавилась папка, нужно добавить хотя бы один файл из неё.

```
# Можно добавить всё содержимое папки
git add foo
# но достаточно хотя бы одного файла
git add foo/file.txt
git commit -m'message'
# теперь папка добавлена
```

Если файлов в папке нет, то есть общепринятая практика — создать файл с именем `.gitkeep` (точка в начале важна).

```
# создаём пустой файл любым способом, например через touch
touch foo/.gitkeep
git add foo/.gitkeep
git commit -m'message'
```

---

Если вы проделали вышеуказанные инструкции, но не видите папку при просмотре файлов на Bitbucket (или GitHub, GitLab и т.п.), проверьте выбранную в данный момент ветку. Все эти сервисы по умолчанию показывают состояние из ветки `master`. Если ваша папка была добавлена в другой ветке, нужно переключиться на просмотр этой ветки.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал git add folder и папка добавилась

Comment: @MyNick как всё просто оказалось, не пригодились мои описания особых случаев ))

Comment: Может еще пригодятся в будущем. Я не смог это с помощью Git GUI сделать

Comment: @MyNick что именно не смогли сделать?

Comment: Добавить внутреннюю папку локального репозитария на Bitbucket. Как git add folder сделать с помощью Git GUI?